# Ensure integrity of exe files in Golang

Tags: security, go

I have a question on deployment of `.exe` file developed using Go Language.

.exe files will be deployed on the customer machines. Which means the integrity of the files (the files are not corrupted, infected) is important.

What should be the approach to ensure that the .exe file is not infected, corrupted or replaced?

(for example
.Net binaries can be signed at compilation, which ensures integrity, and they can be digitally signed by a certificate, which ensures the source of the binary.)

Do we have any such precautions in Golang?

Thanks

Comment: you can publish a checksum of your binary files on your website for example to ensure they are not corrupted. Like many linux distro do with their images...

Comment: i'll point out that hosting checksums over http are easily spoofed by a mitm attack, and checksums over https can be spoofed by a highly resourced attacker

Comment: Let me add on to my question, so we have a main scheduler that usually runs on our client machine and this scheduler executes other .exe files. There is a possibility that one of the exe files get corrupted and we wont know about it.  Our scheduler will keep on executing the file. Checksum is one great way of ensuring this, are there any other methods?

Comment: Just like .Net executables, Go executables can be signed with `signtool`.

Comment: You can cryptographically sign your binary and verify it later with standard tools. Having a binary self-verify is of limited use, since a malicious attacker modifying the binary can also modify the check. You need external tooling that's known to be secure, either provided by the OS or another resource (like gpg).

Answer (score -2):

Use installers such as Inno Setup, InstallShield or Wise Installer. They can check the integrity of the files before installation.

Inno Setup supports for digitally signed installs and uninstalls, including dual signing (SHA1 & SHA256).

InstallShield uses MD5 checks the integrity of the package.

Comment: It was better if you posted this as a comment.